# Deep population is not working in moongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a boq model

Like :

```
var BOQSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,    
    products: [{ product: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }, config: {} }],
}
```

and product model is like:-

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
ratecard: [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "RateCard"}]
});
```

and then a ratecard model

```
var RateCardSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
});
```

now in get call of BOQ, i want to populate product and rate card of product

this is how I am trying but not woking

```
exports.getById = function (req, res) {
    var populate_fields = [
        {
            path: 'products.product',
            model: 'Product',
            populate:{
            path: 'products.product.ratecard',
            model: 'RateCard'
        }
        },
        {
            path: 'customer',
            model: dbSchema.ab_customers
        },
        {
            path: 'location',
            model: dbSchema.ab_city
        }        
    ]
    BOQ.findOne({ _id: req.params.id, isDeleted: false }).populate(populate_fields).exec(function (err, data) {
        if (err) { return res.send(err); }
        if (!data) { return res.json(401); }
        res.status(200).json({ boq: data });
    });
};
```